# Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, salesforce

I am working on a salesforce application which is hitting an API built using ruby on rails. Initially this application was working fine until I faced errors while deploying the application using Jenkins. I checked the logs and it mentions "Stronger security is required, To access this website, update your web browser or upgrade your operating system to support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2. Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0".

What can i alter within my ROR application to resolve this error. I have already tried adding openssl gem to my gemfile but the issue still persists. Here is the error log:

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0">
<tr><td width="100%" height="100%"><div class="content"><h1>Stronger security is required</h1><div class="simple"><p>To access this website, update your web browser or upgrade your operating system to support TLS 1.1 or TLS 1.2.</p><p>For more information, see <a href="https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000221207&amp;language=en_US" target="_blank">Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0</a>.
</p></div></div></td></tr>
</table
```

Comment: Depends how you host your app. It is quite unlikely that your ruby application is doing the https termination itself (as opposed to having something like nginx in front)

Comment: The application is deployed over heroku.

Comment: Then tls version isn't under your control (as I understand things). Are you sure it is requests to your app that are triggering this error (and not, for example, requests made by Jenkins to a salesforce API )? Or is this happening when you make requests to a salesforce API?

Comment: The error occurs when I deployed the code using Jenkins and as this is the only error is see in the logs so I came to conclusion that this error is due to the salesforce API being called and the TLS version being 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

Please see if this works for you.

1. Find the openssl version. You can use the following command "**openssl
   version**" in command line. Ensure that the version is 1.0.1 or higher.
2. TLS 1.1 / TLS 1.2 support starts from
   OpenSSL 1.0.1
   (https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/060184c347822b11dff3db6bef915c04a564c4e4)
3. Set **ssl_version** on your SSLContext:

   ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new 
   ctx.ssl_version = :TLSv1_2

Answer (score 0):

Which version of ruby and openssl did you try? According [Salesforce documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000221207&language=en):

> **Ruby**
>
> Compatible with the most recent version when linked to OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher.
>
> **Ruby 2.0.0**
>
> TLS 1.2 is enabled by default when used with OpenSSL 1.0.1
> or higher. Using the :TLSv1_2 (preferred) or :TLSv1_1 symbols with an
> SSLContext's ssl_version helps ensure that TLS 1.0 or earlier is
> disabled.
>
> **Ruby 1.9.3 and below**
>
> The :TLSv1_2 symbol does not exist in 1.9.3 and below, but it is
> possible to patch Ruby to add that symbol and compile Ruby with
> OpenSSL 1.0.1 or higher.

Comment: I have added openssl gem 0.2.0. Ruby version is 2.2.2.

Comment: I think you need to check that this version allow to use TLS 1.1 or 1.2, possible it's the cause of issue.